# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error for below solution class

Tags: java

```java
class Solution {
    public void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
        
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == 0) {
                for (int j=arr.length-1;j>i;j--) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                }
                if (i!=arr.length) {
                arr[i+1] = arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `-1` here :

```
if (i!=arr.length) {
  arr[i+1] = arr[i];
}
```

If `i == arr.length - 1` then `arr[i + 1]` is out of bound.

Try with :

```
if (i != arr.length - 1) {
  arr[i+1] = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[j] = arr[j+1]; // index is out of bound when j=arr.length-1
```